# Kendo UI - Text color change when under modification

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have provided a working demo.

[Demo in Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iQOwIVAg)

Is it possible to change the text color went under modification? 
For example, when I click on **Edit** button, the whole rows will change to **blue** color text and if I click **Cancel** back to normal color.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I manage to accomplished this by create a hidden field.

On [edit event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit), I need to add:

```
function(e) {   
    e.model.set("HiddenColumnName", "Y");
    highlightBlue();
},
```

then on [cancel event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/cancel), I need to add this as well.

```
function(e) {
    e.model.set("HiddenColumnName", "N");
},
```

and last but not least the highlight color function.

```
function highlightBlue() {
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var data = grid.dataSource.data();

$.each(data, function (i, row) {
    if (row.HiddenColunName == "Y") {
        $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ').css("background-color", "blue"); 
    } 
})
}
```

Here a I provide a [working demo.](https://dojo.telerik.com/iQOwIVAg/5) Don't forget to make the field hidden.